# Call javascript function at specific times of day

Tags: javascript, time

So I have the following code and it works very well for one specific time of day eg: 4pm but I would like to also call this specific function on other times within the day.

I may need to also call it at 7am, or 11am, or 7am, 11am, and 4pm. any help would be great.

```
setInterval(function interval(){    
    var now = new Date();
    var time = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 14, 0, 0, 0) - now;
    if (time < 0) {
         time += 86400000;
    }    
    setTimeout(function () {
        my_function();
        timeout();
    }, time);
    return interval;
}(),1800000);
```

Comment: local time or server time?

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive it would be local time

Comment: @RocketHazmat this currently calls a function at 4pm every day, I would also like to be able to call this at other times within the day. eg: 7pm or 3am or 11 etc.

Comment: @Rune yes I do, I was thinking about using an array of hours I want to call function on. Then using the current hour to decide what I should call on next. I was really just looking for ideas rather than code.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this: checks every hour if the current hour matches your array of wanted hours and if it does, executes a custom function

```
function checkHour(){
    var d = new Date();
    var hours_to_run=[1,13,17,23];
    if(hours_to_run.indexOf(d.getHours()) != -1){
        runCustomFunction();
    }
    setTimeout(checkHour, getMilisecondsLeft());

}

function runCustomFunction(){
    console.log('yay its 1am, 1pm, 5pm or 11pm!!');
}

function getMilisecondsLeft(){
    var d = new Date();
    return 1000*60*60 - (d.getMinutes()*1000*60 + d.getSeconds()*1000+ d.getMilliseconds());    
}

setTimeout(checkHour, getMilisecondsLeft());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this. It schedules a timeout for each of the required hours, and then reschedules any time one of these timeouts elapses:

```
function schedule(time) {
    var now = new Date(),
        next = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 
                        time, 0, 0, 0),
        diff = next - now;

    if (diff < 0) {
        diff += 86400000;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        my_function();
        schedule(time);
    }, diff);
}

var times = [7, 11, 16];

times.forEach(schedule);
```